# undefined method `infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007f7fb3a62b80> (NoMethodError)

Tags: methods, undefined

I'm currently on Chapter 7 of Hartl's Tutorial, and every time I run

bundle exec rspec spec/

the following results:

```
/Users/siciliana/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:31:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007f7fb3a62b80> (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core.rb:79:in `configure'
        from /Users/siciliana/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/siciliana/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:12:in `require'
        from /Users/siciliana/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `map'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load_spec_files'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:11:in `block in autorun'
```

Can someone please explain what is happening here to an absolute newbie?

**spec_helper.rb :**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

#
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"

end
```

Comment: Please show your spec_helper file

Comment: did you recently upgrade rspec? I just upgraded to 2.6 and started having this same problem

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error (although not following the tutorial).

I believe this setting requires `'rspec/rails'`

My solution was to move the line

```
config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = # whatever
```

From `spec_helper.rb` to `rails_helper.rb`.